# Set min and max to TextBox depending on item selected from DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there a way from client side to change a TextBox min and max length and validate like rangevalidator, depending on item selected from a dropdownlist?
Lets say I select the first element from the dropdownlist, the textbox min and max value has to be 2 and 4 and the max length 4. I was thinking on using RangeValidator and also onChange event? Any solution/recommendation to implement this?

EDIT: Something like this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" MaxLength="4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Insert correct value."
MinimumValue="2" MaximumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>

'CodeBehind
Populated dropdownlist.
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "ChangeRangeValidatorValues();")

'Javascript function
        function indexChanged()
        {
            var textbox=document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>');
            var droplist=document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>');
            var rangevalidator=document.getElementById('<%=RangeValidator1.ClientID%>');

        if (droplist.selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            textbox.maxLength=5;
            rangevalidator.minimumvalue=<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValue"] %>;
            rangevalidator.maximumvalue=rangevalidator.minimumvalue;
        }else if (ddl.selectedIndex == 1){
            ..
        }else if (ddl.selectedIndex == 2) {
            ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code whatever you have done and please post your question with its context. Just text description will not help you to get solutions.

Comment: Added pseudo example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this if you are using c# asp.net. if any help comment and if answer is usefull please tick the answer for help other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#DropDownList1').on('change', function () {
               var responseId = $(this).val();
               alert(responseId);

           $("#TextBox1").attr('maxlength', $(this).val());
       });
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very nice approximation that I want. There are a few things to comment:
I need to set the min and max of the textbox to the same value, if possible, from the appsettings?
Alert with messagebox that the textbox is not valid ie. textbox length required or not satisfied.

Comment: you want range of textbox min length 2 and max length 4  OR min  value of textbox 2 and max value is 4 what you want exactly value or range?

Comment: The value.
For example textbox minvalue=0 maxvalue=9999 for rangevalidator and maxlength=4 for textbox. correct values for the textbox should be any number from 0 to 9999.

Comment: I have edited the answer change it according your need. here i have select from dropdown and set the lenth and min max value. and you can check to put value in textbox it working fine.